# Setting MaxLength gives you error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, maxlength

Following is one of the property in my MVC model.

```
[Display(Name = "Event ID")]
[MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Event ID can be of maximum 8 characters long")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="Event ID must be entered")]
public Nullable<int> ID_EVENTO { get; set; }
```

I have bound the model with a View, and when I try to click "Submit" button, it gives following runtime error -

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Array'

While, if I remove the "MaxLength" attribute, it starts working.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`MaxLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute.aspx) is used to specify the maximum length of array or string data allowed in a property.

Your `ID_EVENTO` is a nullable `int` (rather than array or string), that's why the attribute doesn't work. Sounds like you either want to remove the attribute or use a different one - [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx) or something?

Comment: yes, that's right. I removed MaxLength, and have added Int32, which resolved this issue.

Comment: What an absolute train-wreck of an error message. But this answer put me on track, thanks. :)

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on a project I inherited. the type was a nullable int, simply removed the MaxLength attribute from my viewmodel. Thanks ;)